# Laravel bug all pages redirect to 404 page

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404

I'm running laravel 4 and as of a few hours ago, my entire site started redirecting to the default 404 page.  No code changes had been made prior.  I have already tried to restart the server.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: usually when this happens is related with your routes or web server configuration. Can you check if are everything ok?

Comment: see storage/logs/laravel.log